# Jmeter manual file upload Post request

Tags: php, asp.net, post, upload, jmeter

after strugelling for about a week to get an old ASP.net site to accept a multipart form Post request I finally got it to work with a bit of a work around the trick is that Jmeters multipart form functionallity wasnt working properly for this site, so now i have to write the Post request in the Body manually. But the problem is again on the upload file part. I am able to upload empy .txt files but i am unable to upload .png .jpeg i susspect that i am doing something wrong. I read on a site that i am supposed to use _FileToString somehow to upload an existing file but i have no idea how i am supposed to do that. 
[Full POST request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lqpE.png)

> WebKitFormBoundaryBbo97BWEj5UehRpp
>       Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$8$9$fu_appDocument$fu_document";
>   filename="StacktraceKnijki.png"
>       Content-Type: image/png

Can someone help me turn this into a working upload file request? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just record the file upload request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)? JMeter should be smart enough to produce the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler from the captured request.

The only pre-requisite is having your `StacktraceKnijki.png` file in JMeter's "bin" folder during the recording process, see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: As i said i have some problems with jmeter proxy and the workaround is to write the Body manually, see for more information -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144842/jmeter-performance-test-on-asp-net-form-losing-session